# How to ensure a method is using a single instance at a time

Tags: java, synchronization

This may be a simple question,but still it is a problem for me.I am having a class that have method called `task` and i want to ensure only one instance of this class can run this method at a time.I have implemented it like this and am i doing it correct way?

```
class A{

 public void task(){
   synchronized(A.this){ 
   //method stuff 
   }
 }

}

class B{
  public static void main(String a[]){
  new A().task();
  }
}

class C{
  public static void main(String a[]){
  new A().task();
  }
}
```

If `B` started the `task` and before it completes `C` also came to task i want to `C` to wait until `B` completes.
so far it seems works.But i want to know is this the correct way,

thank you.

Comment: I changed A.this to A.class,but still both B and C access the task same time :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. As you have it, you guarantee that only one thread will execute `task()` on a given instance at a time -- but separate instances can still run `task()` at the same time. That is, if you did this (in pseudo-code):

```
Thread t1 = new A().task();
Thread t2 = new A().task();
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Then since each thread creates a separate instance of `A`, they'll each be able to run `task()` at the same time.

You need to synchronize on a `static` field (or `A.class`), or make `task()` a static, synchronized method (in which case `synchronized` locks based off of the `Class` object).

Answer (score 2):

synchronized(A.this) will rely on your instance of A. 
In your case, that instance could be different i.e a thread running B.main() and another thread running C.main() will both create a different instance of A. Therefore one of them will be able to access `public void task()` even though it's already being accessed by the other one.

If you only want to make sure that one thread at a time can access that task method, you can do it this way:

```
    class A{ 
       private static final Object myLock = new Object ();

         public void task() { 
            synchronized(myLock) {  
               //method stuff  
            } 
         } 
    }
```

You could also have a look at the [Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html).